# Symfony LockableTrait - unlock after error/timeout

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am using LockableTrait https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/lockable_trait.html for preventing my command to be executed simultaneously. Because of error/timeout command is locked now so I can not run it again anymore without removing LockableTrait functionality.

How can I can remove lock manually? Command line or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are running command with: `$ bin/console app:say-hello`

This is how you can manually kill it.

```
$ ps aux | grep -i app:say-hello | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: @mcyg Great. If you could kindly accept the answer, that would be helpful to others as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to find and kill the process. Then you will able to run the command again. I'm assuming you are on linux, the commands will be different in Windows.

To find the process:
`pidof php`

It should print an process id. To kill the process: `kill "id"`